# All $http requests are returning -1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am working on an app using ionic.  Just today, all of my `$http` requests started failing by returning -1 status codes.  This is happening when I run with `ionic serve`, `ionic run browser` and `ionic emulate ios`.

These `$http` requests are not necessarily remote, either.  It's failing to load the HTML files inside of `www/template`.  Any help with debugging would be greatly appreciated!

Some more details:
When running `ionic serve`, it loads `index.html` just fine, which loads my `app.js`.  That in turn sets up an HTTP interceptor and loads the states using `$stateProvider`:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ionic.service.core', 'starter.controllers', 'setup.controllers', 'settings.controllers', 'history.controllers', 'graph.controller'])
...
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $analyticsProvider) {
        ...
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', function ($q, $location) {
            return {
                'request': function (config) {
                    // Setup authorization token...
                    return config;
                },  
                'responseError': function (response) {
                    if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                        $location.path('/login');
                    }   
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }   
            };  
        }]);
        ...
            $stateProvider.state('login', {
            cache: false,
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })  

            // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
            .state('tab', {
                url: '/tab',
                abstract: true,
                cache: false,
                controller: 'TabCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
            })
...
```

My browser's javascript console is filled with these errors:

```
ionic.bundle.js:25000 GET http://localhost:8100/templates/tabs.html net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:25000sendReq @ ionic.bundle.js:24793serverRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:24503processQueue @ ionic.bundle.js:29127(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:29143$eval @ ionic.bundle.js:30395$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:30211$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:30503(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:32332completeOutstandingRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:19194(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:19470
ionic.bundle.js:25000 GET http://localhost:8100/templates/login.html net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:25000sendReq @ ionic.bundle.js:24793serverRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:24503processQueue @ ionic.bundle.js:29127(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:29143$eval @ ionic.bundle.js:30395$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:30211$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:30503(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:32332completeOutstandingRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:19194(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:19470
```

When I drop a breakpoint in the interceptor, it intercepts the requests for these local HTML files and shows the response status code as -1.

UPDATE 1:
It keeps getting stranger... if I clear out the local storage, it works... once.  I use local storage to store the logged in user account, so when I clear the storage and refresh, it successfully loads the pages.  After I log in, all the requests stop working.

Comment: Worth mentioning that I did revert with my source control to a known good version and it was still failing with the same cause.  This leads me to believe that it's not necessarily a problem with my source.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to give an answer here. -1 just means that the request wasn't sent, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http . I guess you may debug `request` inteceptors and `config` in particular.

Comment: @Pete I have exactly the same issue with angular.
All the same, when I clean local storage all works good.
And I have tried to checkout from previous git branches - it not helped.
Did you found any solution for fix this strange behavior?

Comment: My experience is that -1 is kind of a catch-all when there's some problem with communication.  If you got back a 200, 400, 404, 500, etc... that meant that the system could communicate successfully with the other server and got a response.  -1 means (I think) that it couldn't even communicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a lot of time during investigation this issue and finally find out the problem.
In my case I have interceptor which adds Bearer Authorization data to each request, all worked amazing until this Bearer had small size, however I made design mistake and added a large amount of data to it after that problems started.
After minimizing Bearer request size all work as expected.

Comment: I wish I remembered exactly how I fixed my issue, but it was months ago.  It had to do with the Bearer authorization as well.  I'll mark your answer up.